# Salesforce DX can't see files created in IntelliJ Illuminated Cloud

Tags: salesforcedx, illuminatedcloud

I created an Enterprise Scratch Org using Salesforce DX and created additional Admin user on it. After that I used IntelliJ Illuminated Cloud to connect with that org in a regular way (not using DX) and created a random class.

Unfortunately when I use `sfdx force:source:status` DX doesn't see that new class added. I decided to give it another try and modified the same class directly through SF UI - it worked, DX noticed changes.

Do you have any idea how to notify SFDX of changes made through IC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The experienced behaviour is not tied to Illuminated Cloud.

Creating an additional user in a Scratch Org is not guaranteed to work. If you want changes to be detected and pulled, use the default user.

Comment: That's no good news. Can you share some documentation/SF response link with that answer?

Comment: I would have if I one was available. If you skim through the DX Trailblazer Community you might find several related posts. https://success.salesforce.com/0F93A000000HTp1